# .latest date for latest files directory in unix

Tags: unix

Can someone please explain .latest to me? I can't find any relevant post on websites.

For example:
In date directory which has two directories:

```
Aug24_2013_11_00_24
May03_2013_14_30_30
```

usage:

```
less /tmp/date/.latest
```

display:

```
Aug24_2013_11_00_24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files whose name begins with a period don't show up in normal directory listings.  If you do

ls -al

where -a means "all" and forces the display of those normally hidden files, you should see that there's a .latest file in your directory, and, probably, that it was created at about 11:00 AM on August 24th.  Either your system automatically overwrites that file whenever a new file is created in that directory, or (more likely IMHO), the application that created those files also writes the name of the new file to .latest when it creates a new date file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state your platform, which may well have something to do with this.  As no such file exists on my system, it's clear you are either talking about some sort of affectation of your platform, or whatever application created that directory.  Please try to be more specific.